# Tarantool load balancing with master-master configuration

Tags: nosql, load-balancing, replication, round-robin, tarantool

I had cluster with two master nodes in replica set. I call vshard.router.callrw api, but request sent always only to first (leader) master. How should I send request to all masters with load balancing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current vshard version doesn't support multimater configuration (https://github.com/tarantool/vshard/issues/165). But you could use "callro" for such purposes.